# Importing local jar of different java version in a maven project

Tags: java, maven

I want to import a local jar SPK-1.0.jar built on Java 1.8 into the maven project using java 17.
I am using maven-install-plugin. I changed the parent pom and module pom as below:

Parent pom

```
<plugin>
                    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                      <execution>
                            <id>local-spk-sdk</id>
                            <phase>clean</phase>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>install-file</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <file>${project.main.basedir}/lib/SPK-1.0.jar</file>
                          <groupId>com.org.services.spkservice</groupId>
                          <artifactId>SPKClient</artifactId>
                                <version>1.0</version>
                                <packaging>jar</packaging>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
```

Module pom dependency

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.org.services.spkservice</groupId>
      <artifactId>SPKClient</artifactId>
      <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

I verified the path in local m2 and can confirm that the jar is present in `~/.m2/repository/com/org/services/spkservice` location

When I try to import the class with logic into my java file I get this error:

```
 package com.org.services.spkservice does not exist
```

Does anyone know what might be missing here?

Comment: Please check whether your JAR is correctly bound to your Maven project. In Eclipse you would go to `Package View > Maven Dependencies`. There you can check whether the JAR contains the expected class, too.

Comment: @PaulSchimmer just as a sanity check, `jar tvf ~/.m2/repository/com/org/services/spkservice/SPKClient-1.0.jar` (fix the path so that it is pointing at the jar itself) - does like `com/org/services/spkservice/SomeClassInThere.class` right? Let's eliminate 'the SPKService jar is broken' as a cause.